# How do I get the Unix epoch in seconds for a date without time?

Tags: go

In Go, how do I get the Unix epoch in seconds for a date without time?

For example, if I want the Unix epoch seconds for the current time, [I can use](https://gobyexample.com/epoch):

```
today := time.Now().Unix()
```

For instance, if the current date+time is 2021-12-31 11:56:01, I want to get the Unix epoch in seconds for 2021-12-31 00:00:00.  Is there an easy way to do this, or do I have to convert to a string, manipulate the string, then parse the string?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yes, I'm sorry I should have been more clear. What I want is for the time portion of the `time` (which is actually a date + time) to be zero. So if the current date+time is `2021-12-31 11:56:01`, I want to get the Unix epoch in seconds for `2021-12-31 00:00:00`. I'll update the question to make this clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [time.Truncate](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Time.Truncate) for rounding the time to the full day:

```
today_00 := time.Now().Truncate(24*time.Hour).Unix()
```